# Hibernate @OrderBy anottation and MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I try implement `@OrderBy` hibernate annotation, but get error `Unknown column 'matches0_.start' in 'order clause'`.

```
...
@Entity
@Table(name ="algo")
public class Algo{
  ...
  @JsonView(Views.Internal.class)
  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
  @OrderBy(clause = "start") // want order list by start
  protected List<DbMatch> matches = new ArrayList<DbMatch>();
  ...
```

DbMatch entity extend match class with `start` field:

```
...
@Entity
@Table(name="matches")
public class DbMatch extends Match{
...
```

Match class and `start` field:

```
...
@MappedSuperclass
public class Match {
  @Column(columnDefinition="DATETIME")
  @JsonSerialize(using=JsonDateSerializer.class)
  @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
  private Date start;
  ...
```

Comment: Can you show your `matches` table in database? Try to use `@OrderBy("start ASC")` instead of `@OrderBy(clause = "start")` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using `org.hibernate.annotations.OrderBy` which expects an *SQL clause*.

You should use `javax.persistence.OrderBy` instead, which expects a property name:

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="algo")
public class Algo{
  ...
  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
  @OrderBy("start")
  protected List<DbMatch> matches = new ArrayList<DbMatch>();
```